# What is the overhead traffic of a TCP connection (plus TCP clarifications)?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-traffic

We have a TCP connection.

1. Nothing is sent over; how many traffic(bytes) are needed for each second to keep that connection open?
2. What is the duration of opening a connection from a client in South America to a server in North Europe?
3. If I have to send small amount of data (max 256bytes) at x seconds interval, what would be x for which is better to close the connection and reopen again instead of keeping the connection always open?

I do not expect exact data - estimates will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

1) none.

2) some time.  Try it and see.  For a rough estimate, ping one end from the other and double it.

3) try it.  It depends on bandwidth and, more importantly, latency. These vary over wide ranges.  Usually, it's better, speed-wise, to keep connections open.  256 bytes at intervals of seconds? I would keep the connection open, especially over paths with possibly high latency, (eg. intercontinental).

Answer (score 3):

**1.** According to the TCP/IP standard, nothing. However, depending on the network conditions and any middleboxes (NAT devices, firewalls, etc.), a connection with no data going over it may be dropped. That could be a staic timeout (say two minutes, or ten minutes, or an hour), or it could be based on a least-recently-used table in some device.

**2.** It depends on a lot of factors, and the biggest delay may be from the client's local network rather than the intercontinental connection. However, the surface of the earth between the points is about 40 light-millisenconds, so (without TCP Fast Open) that would be 120 ms for the first data packet to get from the client to the server and 40 ms for the response, 80 ms more than in an active connection.

**3.** Assuming no broken middleboxes, always better to keep the connection open. However, the delay to recover from a "silently dropped" connection may be a lot longer than the time to open a new one; it might be appropriate for the client to manage its own timeout (on hte order of a second or so), and open a new connection and retry the last message if it hasn't gotten a response by then. Depends on what you're sending; transactional messages might merit such explicit fast retry more than a remote copy of syslog.